# Logstash file input and avro codec parsing problem

Tags: plugins, logstash, avro, codec

All,
I am having some issue with getting Logstash file input and avro codec to work together.
The idea is to read an avro file and extract a json object and then insert it into Elasticsearch.

Below is my config file.

```
  input {
  file {
  path => "C:/dev/testData/xxx/weather.avro"
  start_position => "beginning"
  codec => avro {
        schema_uri => "C:/dev/testData/xxx/weather.avsc"
    }

  sincedb_path=>"C:/dev/testData/property/db"

  }
 }

output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Here is the log:

2018-10-18T13:45:09,523][DEBUG][filewatch.tailmode.handlers.grow] read_to_eof: get chunk
[2018-10-18T13:45:09,599][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] Received line {:path=>"C:/dev/testData/chewer/weather.avro", :text=>"Obj\x01\x04\x14avro.codec\bnull\x16avro.schema\xF2\x02{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Weather\",\"namespace\":\"test\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"station\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"time\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"temp\",\"type\":\"int\"}],\"doc\":\"A weather reading.\"}\x00\xB0\x81\xB3\xC4"}
[2018-10-18T13:45:10,155][ERROR][filewatch.tailmode.handlers.grow] read_to_eof: general error reading C:/dev/testData/chewer/weather.avro {"error"=>"#", "backtrace"=>["org/jruby/ext/stringio/StringIO.java:788:in `read'", "C:/logstash-6.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:106:in`read'", "C:/logstash-6.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:93:in `read_bytes'", "C:/logstash-6.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/io.rb:99:in`read_string'"]}
The test files are from Avro's own repo (weather.avro)

I use avro  1.8.2 and logstash-codec-avro-3.2.3-java.
Please advise.
Gordon